# Menu Lateral - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin-forms

Estou criando uma projeto em `Xamarin.Forms` quem implementa um menu lateral (`Master/Detail`). Até agora consegui exibir o menu corretamente e listar alguns itens nele, a ideia é ao clicar em um desses itens do menu abrir uma outra página e aqui é onde esta meu problema.

Como estou usando modelo `MVVM`, minha `View` está fazendo binding com uma `ViewModel`, quando eu seleciono um dos itens do menu gera uma `exception` que não estou conseguindo resolver.

Mostrarei o codigo para ficar mais claro:

**View:**

```
<StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="listaEmpresas" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding ListaMenu}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding ItemSelecionado}">
        <ListView.Header>
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Gray" 
                         WidthRequest="100"  
                         HeightRequest="40">
                <Label Text="Menu de Navegação" 
                       TextColor="White" FontSize="18"
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ListView.Header>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Nome}" 
                                   FontSize="15"
                                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
public partial class MasterView : ContentPage
{
    public MasterViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public MasterView (ItensMenu menu)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        this.ViewModel = new MasterViewModel();
        this.BindingContext = this.ViewModel;
     }

    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ItensMenu>(this, "ItemSelecionadoMenu",
            (msg) =>
            {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new VeiculoView());
                App.MasterDetail.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new VeiculoView());
            }); 
    }
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MasterViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string teste { set; get; }
    public List<ItensMenu> ListaMenu { get; set; }

    public MasterViewModel()
    {
        this.teste = "Teste";
        this.ListaMenu = new List<ItensMenu>
        {
            new ItensMenu {Nome = "Creditos", Id = "1" },
            new ItensMenu {Nome = "Editar Perfil", Id = "2"},
            new ItensMenu {Nome = "Veiculos", Id = "3"},
            new ItensMenu {Nome = "Historico", Id = "4"},
            new ItensMenu {Nome = "Alertas", Id = "5"}
        };
    }

    private ItensMenu itemSelecionado;

    //Pegar o valor do item Selcionado do Menu
    public ItensMenu ItemSelecionado
    {
        get
        {
            return itemSelecionado;
        }
        set
        {
            itemSelecionado = value;

            if (value != null)
            {
                MessagingCenter.Send<ItensMenu>(itemSelecionado, "ItemSelecionadoMenu");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Quando clico em um dos itens ocorre a seguinte exception:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ocorreu

Um detalhe é que quando eu troco o codigo `Navigation.Async` por um `DisplayAlert` no CodeBehind ele funciona normal.

Comment: Eu não tenho certeza, mas acredito que se você colocar um `try/catch` no bloco de código que está dentro do delegate anônimo que está sendo passado no `MessagingCenter` pode ajudar. Eu acredito que deva estar avendo uma vialação de acesso de thread. Já tentou escrever o `PushAsync` dentro de um bloco `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`? Percebi também que você está fazendo o push duas vezes... é isso mesmo? Foi intencional?

Comment: Ola Diego, eu esqueci de editar, o PushAsync é apenas uma vez, eu deixei ali um outro método que estava tentando. Vou tentar do modo que você indicou e volto com a resposta. Obrigado.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza, eu coloquei o bloco try/catch dentro do delegate e o problema é la mesmo, porem não consigo verificar qual é. voce poderia me dar um exemplo de como usar o bloco Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread? procurei saber como faz, mas não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Claro. [Veja esse exemplo no dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UzA9Os). Geralmente precisa colocar esse cara quando voce está fazendo uma intervenção na thread da UI a partir de uma thread de background. Como o seu método tá assincrono, e tem esse delegate anônimo, pode ser que seja o caso. Se não for, por favor, edite sua pergunta incluindo mais detalhes do erro que você está tendo a partir do que encontrar no `catch` que você adicionou no método para testar.

Answer (score 1):

Vou deixar uns trechos de códigos para você tentar replicar na sua aplicação, caso tenha alguma dúvida estou à disposição.

**--------- MasterDetailView ------------ View**

**Observação: Trocar os trechos do código que eu te disser.**

**Trocar x:Class para o nome da sua classe.**

**Trocar xmlns:pages para o nome do caminho das suas Views.**

**Trocar pages:MenuLateralView para o nome da sua View referente ao menu lateral.**

**Trocar pages:CheckInMenuView para o nome da sua View que irá ser a página inicial do seu aplicativo.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  x:Class="YesShowroom.Views.MasterDetailView"
                  xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:YesShowroom.Views">
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <pages:MenuLateralView x:Name="MasterPage" />
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <pages:CheckInMenuView />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

**--------- MasterDetailView ------------ Code Behind**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MasterDetailView : MasterDetailPage
{
    public MasterDetailView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MasterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += ListView_ItemSelected;
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    }

    private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.SelectedItem as MenuItemModel;

        if (item == null)
            return;

        var page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType);
        page.Title = item.Title;

        Detail = new NavigationPage(page);
        IsPresented = false;

        MasterPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;
    }
}
```

**--------- Classe MenuItemModel ------------**

```
public class MenuItemModel
{
    public MenuItemModel()
    {
        TargetType = typeof(MasterDetailViewDetail);
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Type TargetType { get; set; }
}
```

**--------- MasterDetailViewDetail ------------ View**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="YesShowroom.Views.MasterDetailViewDetail"
             Title="Detail">
  <StackLayout Padding="10">
    <Label Text="Detail"/>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**--------- MasterDetailViewDetail ------------ Code Behind**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MasterDetailViewDetail : ContentPage
{
    public MasterDetailViewDetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**--------- MenuLateralView ------------ View**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="YesShowroom.Views.MenuLateralView"
             Title="Master">
  <StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="MenuItemsListView"
              SeparatorVisibility="None"
              HasUnevenRows="true"
              ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
      <ListView.Header>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="#16335a">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>

          <Label Grid.Column="1"
                 Grid.Row="2"
                 Text="Yes Showroom"
                 TextColor="White"
                 FontSize="28"/>
         </Grid>
      </ListView.Header>
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Padding="15,10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
              <Label VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                     VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                     Text="{Binding Title}" 
                     FontSize="24"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**--------- MenuLateralView ------------ Code Behind**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MenuLateralView : ContentPage
{
    public ListView ListView;

    public MenuLateralView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new MenuLateralViewModel();
        ListView = MenuItemsListView;
    }

    class MenuLateralViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MenuItemModel> MenuItems { get; set; }

        public MenuLateralViewModel()
        {
            MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemModel>(new[]
            {
                new MenuItemModel { Id = 0, Title = "Check In", TargetType = typeof(CheckInMenuView) },
                new MenuItemModel { Id = 1, Title = "Status", TargetType = typeof(StatusView) },
                new MenuItemModel { Id = 3, Title = "Relatório", TargetType = typeof(RelatorioView) },
                new MenuItemModel { Id = 2, Title = "Sair", TargetType = typeof(LoginView) }
            });
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged == null)
                return;

            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```